# Use AWS Lambda for historical / batch data processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I understand that AWS Lambda can be used for real-time event processing.
I have implemented an AWS Lambda in Java 8 which processes Kinesis events.

But how can I use this same Java function to process these historical Kinesis events which I have stored in S3 for past 1 year.
Or let say I want run this AWS Lambda Java function also on some batch workloads.

As of now, what I believe, I'll have to use separate service like AWS Batch, AWS Datapipeline etc. and have to write code in those applications separately.
AWS Batch/Datapipeline does not even support Java jobs/activities.

So technically, I need to maintain codebase having same transformations in 2 different locations/services.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some sort of processing (which might be 1 time processing) to add messages to the Kinesis stream so you don't have 2 processors that are nearly identical doing the same thing.  Assuming that you have more than 1000 objects in S3 I would write 2 processes:

1. Either in a lambda or locally using the cli you would [traverses your S3 directories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html). Whenever it encounters a file that it cares about to either place it in a queue (SQS) or send a message to lambda #2 outlined below.
2. A lambda that (receives a message or pulls from a queue depending on which approach above) takes the bucket and key, retrieves the object out of S3, does any mapping/transformation necessary and adds it to the Kinesis stream.

Some reasons for this approach are:

- Using the S3 api to list objects only get's you the bucket and key.  With lambda's 5 minute limitation you will not be able to process everything in 5 minutes.
- Single Responsibility.  1 lambda is responsible for finding S3 objects, 1. lambda is responsible for fetching the object and doing the processing.  One could argue that you should split the 2nd lambda into multiple steps and that may make sense as well.  I wouldn't put too much effort into it if it's a 1 time thing that you don't plan to reuse.